# A&M Gift Exchange: Ship out your gifts + Feedback on the conspiracy!

Tags: discussion, events, tomato

Now that the deadline for conspiracy gifting draws near, we'd like to remind everyone of that deadline. It's time to get your presents on their way!

Remember the deadline is **November 4th**.

This deadline was chosen so that we can all start unwrapping near the Christmas holidays :)

We will post another meta for showing off your gifts in early December.

If you have questions concerning shipping, please ask one of the moderators either in chat or through the support email **anime.se.giftexchange@gmail.com.** - or ask them here if you don't mind losing anonymity.

[image]

Vroom Vroom! Let's get those packages moving!

---

Another thing we would like to ask those who participated in the Gift Exchange this time is some ***feedback on this year's present consipiracy.***

Did you enjoy this change? What could be improved / done differently? Did you find it easier to decide on a good gift?

Comment: Despite some hiccups, I hope you guys enjoyed the Time of Tomato we've all had!